# SKScene nodes not detecting touch

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, arkit

I am trying to make an ARKit app for ios and the nodes in the scene are not responding to touch. The scene is properly displayed but I haven't been able to detect any touch.

fileNamed: "TestScene" refers to a TestScene.sks file in my project which is empty and I add the node in the code as shown below.

```
let detailPlane = SCNPlane(width: xOffset, height: xOffset * 1.4)

let testScene = SKScene(fileNamed: "TestScene")
testScene?.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

let winner = TouchableNode(fontNamed: "Chalkduster")
winner.text = "You Win!"
winner.fontSize = 65
winner.fontColor = SKColor.green
winner.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)

testScene?.addChild(winner)

let material = SCNMaterial()
material.diffuse.contents = testScene
material.diffuse.contentsTransform = SCNMatrix4Translate(SCNMatrix4MakeScale(1, -1, 1), 0, 1, 0)
detailPlane.materials = [material]

let node = SCNNode(geometry: detailPlane)
rootNode.addChildNode(node)
```

For TouchableNode I have the following class

```
class TouchableNode : SKLabelNode {

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        print("Touch detected")
    }

}
```

Comment: You are using it as a material..... I doubt UI responder will go through materials

Comment: Also, touchable node needs to have isUserInteractionEnabled set to true, not the scene, if you want the touchable node to fire that print line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've achieved this affect using gesture recognize

```
private func registerGestureRecognizers() -> Void {
    let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap))
    sceneView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
}
```

then have a function to handle the tap gesture

```
@objc private func handleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) -> Void {
    let sceneViewTappedOn = sender.view as! SCNView
    let touchCoordinates = sender.location(in: sceneViewTappedOn)
    let hitTest = sceneViewTappedOn.hitTest(touchCoordinates)
    if !hitTest.isEmpty {
        let hitResults = hitTest.first!
        var hitNode = hitResults.node
        // do something with the node that has been tapped
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do **isUserInteractionEnabled = true** first.

So, something like:

```
class TouchableNode : SKLabelNode {
    override init() {
        super.init()
        isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder:  aDecoder)
        isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        print("Touch detected")
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have isUserInteractionEnabled on the SCNView?

Comment: Yes. I have sceneView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true in my ViewController.